# replace forward slash for - using jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace

At the moment I'm replacing spaces with hyphens

```
$( "#" + arrVals.join(',#').replace(/ /g,"-") ).show();
```

How can I also replace / with -

Thanks very much for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just adjust your [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) regex to check for either a space *or* a `/` character, like this:

```js
$( "#" + arrVals.join(',#').replace(/ |\//g,"-") ).show();
```